# Force needed to rotate a load horizontally?

Tags: forces, rotation

I need to rotate a 500lbs(226.8kg and balanced at center of load) telescope horizontally, at up to 90 degrees per sec. Ideally I would like to reach the max speed in a tenth of a sec. I need to buy a stepper motor capable of achieving the force needed to quickly accelerate and rotate the telescope. I found the following equation, and I just need someone to double-check my work and make sure I don't screw up a detail, and buy an unnecessarily over-powered motor, and definitely not an under-sized model (:P):

\begin{align}
    kg &= 226.796185 \\
    radius \text{(meters)} &= 0.4572 \\
    MOI \text{(moment of inertia)} &= kg*radius*radius \\
    degrees &= 90.0/360.0 \\
    rotsPerSec &= degrees/60.0 \\
    radiansPerSecSQRD &= 2*π*rotsPerSec \\
    newtonMeters &= MOI * radiansPerSecSQRD
\end{align}

So basically, just moment of inertia multiplied by the radians per sec gives me the Newton-Meters of force that I need. Does this check out?

Comment: I suggest you read the help into how to format your posts using ${\rm Math}$ and `code` for better readability.

Comment: Are you rotating against gravity or in a horizontal plane ?

Comment: @ja72 Horizontally. I edited the post to note this. Forgot to add it. :/ TY.

Comment: Moment of inertia can depend on the shape of the object. The formula you give ($m \cdot r^2$) is only true for symmetric objects. I do not suppose your telescope is symmetric, but I do not know how important the detail is.

Comment: $90$ degrees per second is *way* fast for a telescope.  You will need a whopping motor and be in danger of damaging things.  I would suggest a target more like $1$ degree per second. But the calculation approach is the same.  The MOI of the telescope is $ML^2/12$ if the scope is uniform in mass per unit length.  The heavy mirror at the end will increase this a bit.

Comment: @Ross Millikan I agree...I dropped the max speed to 90degrees per 2sec, or 45/sec. That may still be fast, but it's an upper esimate, and accounts for me needing to slew quickly to objects. Normally the user won't move more than a couple degrees per second, but I just want the ability to do so in extreme cases. Also, like I said, the load will be balanced with the majority of the body and the mirror itself shifted forward perpendicular to the axis. Mainly I balanced the load so I wouldn't need to brake and lock the scope, but also to accelerate more quickly.

Comment: Moment of inertia times rotational speed gives angular momentum, which is **not** torque.

Comment: To those who closed this topic....HAVE YOU LOST YOUR MINDS? How did I fail to "ask about a specific physics concept and show some effort to work through the problem." I specifically asked how accurate was my calculation of torque need to rotate a horizontal load. I gave my equation (which I thought possibly complete enough to suit my needs), showing at least some effort on my part. :/ Luckily, people answered the question before you shut the topic down and prevented me from getting the insight I needed. Muchos gracias for nothing amigos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you truly want to move 90 degrees in 2 seconds, you need to accelerate up to maximum rate in 1 second and decelerate again.  You have $45=\frac 12 \omega' (1^2)$ or $w'\approx 9.5 ^\circ/sec^2\approx \frac 16 rad/sec^2$ $I=ML^2/12=226 \cdot 0.9^2/12\approx 15 kg\cdot m^2$, so the torque is $2.5 N\cdot m$  If the weight is all at the ends, the MOI triples, so you need $7.5 N\cdot m$ plus the bearing resistance.  If the scope is unbalanced, the real torque requirement will be to hold it against gravity.  This could be much higher.  A motor this strong is not hard to come by.

Comment: This is a stepper motor, and it would make sense to accelerate abruptly for a short perdiod of time, coast at speed and then decellerate abruptly.

Comment: Then your torque requirement is much higher.  More of interest is the speed you can maintain.  Will you have a gear train?  You didn't describe one, but often you want one to get the speed/torque you want

Comment: I will have one depending on the models they offer. The model of stepper motor I was looking at is DEFINITELY way too strong. I'll be getting one twice as strong as that needed for a single scope since I hope to make a binocular system one day too. :P

Answer (score 1):

Torque is mass moment of inertia times rotational acceleration. You need to specify how quickly you need to get to $90\,{\rm deg/s}$. Additionally, you need torque to overcome friction (and drag). Any motor can provide the torque needed when geared right, but doing it at the speed that is needed is the real trick.

$$ T_{motor} = I \dot\omega + T_{friction} $$

Now consider that supplied torque is a function of speed, as well as friction sometimes the above becomes a differential equation. To solve your problem you need to specify more information. You need to specify the friction torque and the time to achieve the slew rate $\omega$.